# PID H-bridge random current spikes

Tags: avr, h-bridge, pid-controller

My H-bridge consists of 4 n-channel MOSFETs. The high side is driven by a basic bootstrap circuit, and the low side is directly driven from the MCU.

Using a PID function to control the motor by its position, set by setpoint. And the 8-bit PWM is generated by timer(s) from the AVR.
Current is read through a shunt resistor and op-amp fed into the ADC.
Highest ADC value in the graph is about 6 A.

I tried many different PID libraries, but the issue still remains.

What could cause such random current spikes?

[image]

H-bridge schematic:
[image]